# Plugin de tradução WordPress

Tags: wordpress, aplicação-web

Eai galera, bom a empresa ta querendo traduzir o site para Inglês e eles usam o WordPress. A ideia é ter um flag do reino unido que ao clicar deixe a pagina toda em inglês. (Obvio hahaha).
Pesquisei e vi sobre o wpml, porem acharam muito caro aqui. Alguem sabe algum outro plugin que faça isso?
A, e vale lembrar que temos todo o texto já traduzido, queremos inserir manualmente.
Apenas não queremos ter que refazer toda o container de novo.

Comment: tenta esse aqui https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso tente instalar o plugin [qTranslate](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/), ele é mais simples que outros e vai manter seu site com dois idiomas.